# C++ I don't know what it means to use "this" and "std::placeholders::_1" when using the callback function

Tags: c++, stdbind, cpprest-sdk

I am trying to make a server by looking at the sample code of cpprestSDK.
But I don't know why I bind in the sample code.

Below is the sample code.

stdafx.h

```
class Handler{
public:
    Handler() {};
    Handler(utility::string_t url);

    pplx::task<void> open() { return m_listener.open(); }
    pplx::task<void> close() { return m_listener.close(); }

private:
    void handle_get(http_request request);
    void handle_put(http_request request);
    void handle_post(http_request request);
    void handle_del(http_request request);
};
```

hander.cpp

```
  
#include "stdafx.hpp"

Handler::Handler(utility::string_t url) : m_listener(url)
{

    m_listener.support(methods::GET, std::bind(&Handler::handle_get, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    m_listener.support(methods::PUT, std::bind(&Handler::handle_put, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    m_listener.support(methods::POST, std::bind(&Handler::handle_post, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    m_listener.support(methods::DEL, std::bind(&Handler::handle_del, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

Looking at the reference for support, it is defined as follows.

`void support (const http::method &method, const std::function< void(http_request)> &handler)`

I thought I could define it like this:

`m_listener.support(methods::GET, &Handler::handle_get);`

But it failed.

Can you tell me why I use "this" and "std::placeholders::_1" when doing a bind?

sample code : https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/archive/blogs/christophep/write-your-own-rest-web-server-using-c-using-cpp-rest-sdk-casablanca

cpprestSDK listener reference : https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1experimental_1_1listener_1_1http__listener.html

Comment: _"I thought I could define it like this_" - and, if you could, how would the compiler know what instance to call that method on? it can't. that's why binding is required, to create a callable that encapsulates not only the identify of a member but also an instance on which to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The member function

```
void support (const http::method &method,
              const std::function< void(http_request)> &handler)
```

expects `handler` to be a callable which has

- an argument of type `http_request`
- a return type `void`.

A plain function `void handle(http_request)` would match this required signature.

If you want to register a (non-`static`) member function this is also possible but you have to provide the object as well (as non-`static` member functions may not be called without object).

The `std::bind(&Handler::handle_get, this, std::placeholders::_1)` acts as (a kind of) adapter to fit your member function (with `this` as bound object) into that requirement.

The `std::placeholders::_1` denotes, where to bind the argument (of type `http_request`) into the wrapped member function call.

A simpler way would be to use a lambda as adapter (instead of the `bind`):

```
m_listener.support(methods::GET, [this](http_request http_req) { this->handle_get(http_req); });
```

or even:

```
m_listener.support(methods::GET, [this](http_request http_req) { handle_get(http_req); });
```

---

Further readings:

- [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)
- [std::placeholders](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders)